# Remover o sustenido(#) do crossroads.js e funcionar sem ele , como fazer?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, routing

Iae galera, então eu uso essa lib para fazer as rotas. porem elas sem vem essa # e mesmo que eu tire, ela ainda nao funciona se eu recarregar no browser

F5 url: www.locahost.com/home = not found
F5 url: www.locahost.com/#home = found

alguem poderia me indicar uma biblioteca ou me ajudar a resolver isso? obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

As *hashs* (#) são padrões nesses tipos de biblioteca, eu não recomendaria tirar. Mas caso queira realmente tirar, adicione um *listener* na url, assim você troca a informação contida lá, por meio da API do Histórico do navegador. Ficaria assim:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
  window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);  
 // do something...
});
```

Veja se isto funciona pra você. Aqui está a documentação do [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Comment: a minha pergunta surgiu porque o durandal js não usa '#' no router então eu precisava pra ficar algo mais amigavel, Obrigado pela resposta !